# How to write a program which says "good morning" and "good night"

Tags: ruby

I need to write a program that says "good morning", "good afternoon", "good evening" and "good night" depending on the clock in Ruby.

I tried a program which doesn't work.

```
def greet(hour_of_clock)

end
if hour == 6 -11 am
puts 'good morning'

elsif hour == 12-4 pm
puts 'good afternoon'

elsif hour == 5-8 pm
puts 'good evening'

else
puts 'good night'

end
local_time = time.new
hour_of_clock = local_time_hou
```

Comment: `6-11` gives `-5`. What time is -5am?

Comment: @varun Ya: You need to find better resources to learn ruby; I would recommend starting with https://rubymonk.com.

Comment: This might have practical use. I know of a monastery where, at breakfast, when the abbot enters the room, the assembled monks always sing, "good mor-ning".  Simimlarly, at dinner they always sing, "good eve-ning". One morning, when the abbot entered the room there was the usual chorus of "good mor-ning", except for one lone, "good eve-ning".  The abbot looked up, surveyed the audience and intoned, "Someone chanted eve-ning".

Comment: To appreciate my comment above, younger readers and readers whose first language is not English may wish to watch the beginning of [this clip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rGyfw3yiMT4).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it:

```
def greet(hour_of_clock)
  if hour_of_clock >= 6 && hour_of_clock <= 11
    puts "Good Morning"
  elsif hour_of_clock >= 12 && hour_of_clock <= 16
    puts "Good Afternoon"
  elsif hour_of_clock >= 17 && hour_of_clock <= 20
    puts "Good Evening"
  else
    puts "Good Night"
  end
end
greet(Time.new.hour)
```

Comment: Than you very much prakash,iam just starting to learn ruby and thanks for ur suggession.

Comment: i have one more question for number 1 to 100 you should print "fizz" if the number is divisible by 3

Comment: @VarunYa Start reading up :-) This site is not for getting your work done.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a `case` statement:

```
def greet(little_hand)
  case little_hand
  when (6..11)  then puts "Good Morning"
  when (12..16) then puts "Good Afternoon"
  when (17..20) then puts "Good Evening"
  else               puts "Good Night"
  end
end
```

Comment: I like this answer with case statement. If I am the OP, I will accept this answer.